# Установить иконку FileChooser в swing Java

Tags: java, swing, icon

Всем привет, пишу приложение с UI на swing Java. Проблема следующая: создаю у себя окно выбора файлов при помощи такой конструкции:

```
JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser(lastPath);
```

Все работает хорошо, но по умолчанию этому окну ставится иконка дефолтная. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как эту иконку сменить? знаю точно что можно, видел на каком то сайте, но не могу найти теперь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в  `fileOpen.showOpenDialog(Component parent)` передать как `parent` основной Jframe приложения с установленной иконкой (см JFrame::setIconImage), то диалог "унаследует" ее.

Если совсем свою иконку нужно поставить, то можно унаследоваться от JFileChooser и переопределить метод `javax.swing.JFileChooser.createDialog`, в котором задать свою иконку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это отлично работает!!!